# Clearcase deliver accepted notice

Tags: clearcase

I have a problem with some programmers. They don't let me know when they deliver, so I do nothing about it.
Is there a way to get a notice when someone delivered?

Thanks.

Comment: Is Clearcase like UPS and FedEx? Is this a programming problem or a problem with programmers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: hit them, hard!

Have a trigger implemented on the clearcase server that send on email on commit or on merge.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4311.html

Answer (score 1):

"deliver" can mean an UCM merge, in which case you can:

- make an intermediate stream where developer delivers whenever they want
- simply lock the integration stream in order to be the only one able to deliver on it (meaning you can trigger a deliver from the intermediate stream to the integration stream when you want: if the deliver reports something to merge, then you can examine the activities to be merged).